# Can aromatic rings be cyanated using cyanide as a nucleophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitriles

For example, can I convert chlorobenzene into benzonitrile by using potassium cyanide as the reagent?

Comment: Replacing Cl in with CN is benzene can be done but requires a catalyst. Uncatalysed nothing with happen.

Comment: Can you please tell me the catalyst

Comment: There are many sets of conditions in the literature using Pd or Ni catalysis, more info here  https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/C1C/arenes/cyanations.shtm

Comment: If possible, you'd rather start with iodoarenes. One of the well-established method uses copper(I) cyanide. Please see my answer to an earlier question, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63892/will-cyanide-substitute-bromine-in-bromobenzene/63905#63905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chlorobenzene is generally inert to nucleophilic substitution. It was observed by Rosenmund and Braun that **using an ethanolic solution of potassium cyanide** and cuprous cyanide as catalyst at 200°C, chlorobenzene converts to **benzoic acid**. But if the ethanol-cyanide solvent is removed and temperature is raised, then the reaction proceeds to form cyanobenzene. Yield was further improved when ionic liquids like DMF was used. This is Rosenmund-Braun reaction.

**Note**: Working with cyanide is highly dangerous. **Do not handle cyanide until and unless you are a professional chemist.**

**Reference**

1. [Wikipedia: Rosenmund-von Braun reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenmund%E2%80%93von_Braun_reaction)
2. [Will cyanide substitute bromine in bromobenzene?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63892/will-cyanide-substitute-bromine-in-bromobenzene/63905)
3. [Potassium ferrocyanide, $\ce{K4[Fe(CN)6]}$ can be used as a non-toxic source for cyanation.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286148010_K4FeCN6_as_non-toxic_source_of_cyanide_for_the_cyanation_of_aryl_halides_using_Pd-Beta_zeolite_as_a_heterogeneous_catalyst)
4. [There are loads of other catalyst for cyanation like $\ce{ZnCl2}$, palladium or nickel salts](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/C1C/arenes/cyanations.shtm).[@Waylander]